# append preexistent div with data to container jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden `li` or maybe I would need to create one

**HTML**

```
  <li class="instant_comment">
     <div class=image><a href='/channel'><img src='/fr43/prof.jpg' /></a></div>
       <div class=post>[What I comment]</div>
      </li>
```

```
 <form>
    <textarea id=textarea></textare>
    <input type=submit value='answer' id=Comment />
 </form>
```

So anytime I write a new comment, and click on the `comment` button, It appends the preexistent `li.instant_comment` into the `#MyComments` container. So I dont have to pass my profile picture, id_user, channel name, tokens etc by the form. and append it.

**JQUERY**
So, something like this

```
  $("#comment").on("click",function(){

     $(".post")=$("#textarea").val();//add my content to the div
      $("#MyComments").append.(".instant_comment");//append this content to the ul

        });
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, you will find the below solution helpful. Please take note that the form is not submiting at the moment because I have added `e.preventDefault()` in the function. You may use AJAX to submit your form.

```js
$("#comment-form").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var textValue = $("#text-area").val();
  var myComment = "<li class='instant_comment'><div class=image><a href='/channel'><img src='/fr43/prof.jpg' /></a></div><div class=post>"+textValue+"</div></li>";
  $(this).after(myComment);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="comment-form">
    <textarea id="text-area"></textarea>
    <input type=submit value='answer' id="Comment" />
 </form>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you. but in this case I want to clone an existing div, add it the textarea val and then append it to the container. Can it be possible?

Comment: I can't say if it is possible or not but as far as appending a div with dynamic value is concerned, I think this solution is one of the best way to do it because if you append `.instant_comment` it will append that div without any content in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with creating li html from js and append to parent container.

```
 var comment= $("#textarea").val();
 var newLi = "<li class='instant_comment'><div class='image'><a href='/channel'><img src='/fr43/prof.jpg' /></a></div><div class=post>" + comment + "</div></li>";
 $('#MyComments').append(newLi);
```

Comment: @joe let me know if its works for your otherwise i will create a code snip for you.